# How to turn on one of the toggle buttons

Tags: android, xml, togglebutton, interlocked

I want the other toggle button to turn off when one turns on.

```
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/press"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/nomal"></item>
```

This is my togglebutton's xml code This code is made in 'drawable'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below selector as a background of the `ToggleButton` which picks the appropriate drawable when the button changes its check status

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checked" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

and wrap both buttons in a [`RadioGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup); then traverse this group in a loop whenever a button is checked/clicked, and then negates those buttons with `setChecked()` method.

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_btn_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_btn_selector"
            android:onClick="onToggle"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggle_btn_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_btn_selector"
            android:onClick="onToggle"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Behavior**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RadioGroup mGroup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGroup = findViewById(R.id.toggleGroup);
    }

    public void onToggle(View view) {

        ToggleButton checkedBtn = ((ToggleButton) view);

        for (int j = 0; j < mGroup.getChildCount(); j++) {
            ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton) mGroup.getChildAt(j);
            int id = toggleButton.getId();
            if (view.getId() == id)
                continue;
            toggleButton.setChecked(!checkedBtn.isChecked());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup), and add to it 2 [RadioButtons](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton) with you drawable. Checkout second link, it will describes how to do it properly.
Also you need to change your drawable xml press to checked